# Creating "rootNode" subnodes: constructing "BackendServices" in "rootNode": doing migrations: reading actual settings: invalid character '/'

Tags: macos-catalina, docker-desktop

Expected behavior:
Launching Docker Desktop and work with it

Actual behavior:
Crashed with launch and show message:
Something went wrong
Creating "rootNode" subnodes: constructing "BackendServices" in "rootNode": doing migrations: reading actual settings: invalid character '/' looking for beginning of value

macOS Catalina,
Intel chip,
Docker Desktop 4.15.0

Steps to reproduce the behavior

1. click on icon Docker Desktop on iconbar
2. Did nothing and show message
   Something went wrong
   Creating "rootNode" subnodes: constructing "BackendServices" in "rootNode": doing migrations: reading actual settings: invalid character '/' looking for beginning of value

[image]

How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It happening just because corruption of some JSON files.
You need to update the following JSON files as all these file filled with null values -
~\AppData\Roaming\Docker

- forwards.json
- settings.json
- locked-directories

Also you need to update C:\Users<username>.docker\features.json.

PS: You can take these files from one of your colleague/friend (as I did)

Answer (score -1):

Delete the AppData/Roaming/Docker greeted me with the Docker Desktop welcome screen.

Answer (score -1):

By deleting features.json file from C:\Users\Username.docker my docker desktop is starting.